# Photos Live Tile goes blank after some time

Tags: 8.1, photos, live-tiles

On my Nokia 930 (WP 8.1) the photos live tile stops showing photos after a day or so.

When I go to settings and pick shuffle it will work again for some time.

It is set to show favorites, and I have tried removing the tile and adding it again without success.

Comment: Does the tile go black or just freeze on one photo?

Comment: It goes to the theme color, with the label Photos. Basically what it would look like if you would have no photos.

Comment: Odd. I've never seen that behaviour.

Comment: I have now removed some photos from my favorites to see if that makes a difference...

Comment: For me after WP8.1 updates with the increase in data the live tiles sometimes take some time to refresh. Since I have customized my start screen with lots of png images so I sometimes see this behaviour when I suddenly navigate to start screen suddenly while it refreshes all tiles after some time.

Comment: I have removed half of the photos from my favorites, after which the problem was gone. Then I restored all favorites and it seems to be fixed now. Also took a couple of photos and screenshots in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems related to one of my photos. When one particular photo is part of my favorites the live tile has a problem. In addition to a blank tile (solid theme color), I have now also seen the tile fixed to one of the other favorite photos. When it is fixed to the other photo it also does not move (most of the time they slide up/down once in a while).

Answer (score 1):

Try to click settings after you tap the "photo" tile; if it shows "favorite photos", tap it to change it to "all photos"

Comment: I don't want it to show all photos, I want it to show only my favorites. As indicated in my post from last year this problem was related to one particular photo which, after removing it from my favorites the problem was gone.